# JavaScript addEventListener

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, addeventlistener

When I use `addEventListener` only once, like in the example file input, should I remove the listener as well with `removeEventListener`? Or, if I know that I will not use any of that code anymore, then *garbage collector* will collect all the objects anyway?

Also, if I remove the event listener manually, will it speed up the garbage collector as it makes its job easier?

```
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Comment: It would help to have a bit more context. Where is this code? E.g., is it in a function (for instance, a `change` handler on the input)?

Comment: FYI, in some newest implementations, [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can receive an "options" object as the third argument that will let you set, among other things, a `once` flag that will remove the listener after the first time the event fires. This can be patched into browsers that don't support that behavior yet.

Comment: Use `src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead

Answer (score 3):

> should I remove the listener as well with `removeEventListener`?

That's entirely up to you. Unless you do, it will remain attached.

> Or, if I know that I will not use any of that code anymore, then garbage collector will collect all the objects anyway?

Only if the `FileReader` is eligible for garbage collection. If `reader` isn't eligible for GC, then its handlers remain in memory.

> Also, if I remove the event listener manually, will it speed up the garbage collector as it makes its job easier?

That will vary by implementation.

Note that with your example, you *can't* remove that handler. To remove it, you have to have a reference to it.

Here's an example actually removing it:

```
var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var reader;
var handler;
if (file) {
    reader  = new FileReader();
    handler = function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;

        // Remove this handler
        reader.removeEventListener("load", handler, false);
        reader = handler = null;
    };
    reader.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Note that we remove the reference to the handler both from the event handler list *and* from the `handler` variable, and we make sure to clear our `reader` variable as well so the reader is eligible for GC.

The above may well be overkill, though. Just clearing the `reader` should be sufficient:

```
var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var reader;
if (file) {
    reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;

        reader = null;
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

By release our reference to `reader`, we make the reader eligible for GC, which will also clean up its event handlers.

Comment: So, you would not recommend removing the handler in places where you actually know GC will take care of it?

Comment: @AlexPeterson: I'd neither recommend it nor recommend against it. I mostly don't. If I know it's going to get cleaned up, I don't feel the need to write extra code. Of course, sometimes that means I'm wrong and later I realize I should have written that code -- and then I do. :-) (Although that's only happened maybe twice -- either because I'm usually right, or -- probably -- I just haven't noticed a memory leak because it's been too small to worry about.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really use the listener and (i.e. the event) just once, it makes sense to remove the listener afterwards. In particular if you are somehow concerned about performance.
The garbage collection will not remove the listener, since it does not know if that event may occur again in the future. And because it would not remove the listener by itself, removing it manually does not speed up anything.

Removing it inside the event should be a quite clean solution.

Comment: The GC knows if the event happens in the futures thus collects the whole thing together with the attached listener

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not mandatory to unbind event handlers to events you don't use in the future but unbinding event manually will make a good solution/code.
2. JavaScript's garbage collection will take care of it and free up the reserved memory. It won't remove event listeners to DOM elements that may still have a reference to them in a detached DOM tree.

Comment: Will it speed up GC?